# Java (Android) - BufferOverflowException on putInt

Tags: java, exception, buffer

I try this code :

`byte arr[] = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putInt(1).array()`

But it fails with a `BufferOverflowException`.
Is 1 too big to be stored in 2 bytes ? Or is my problem somewhere else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is 1 too big to be stored in 2 bytes ?

Well, an `int` is... `putInt` always writes 4 bytes. From the [documentation for `ByteBuffer.putInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt-int-)

> Throws:
>
> BufferOverflowException - If there are fewer than four bytes remaining in this buffer

If you only want to put a two-byte integer, use `putShort` instead. If you want to store data in a variable-width encoding (where the space taken depends on the value), you'll probably need to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From javadoc of method [`putInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt(int)):

> **Writes four bytes** containing the given int value, in the current byte order, into this buffer at the current position, and then increments the position by four

You allocated only 2 bytes so the [`BufferOverflowException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/BufferOverflowException.html):

> Unchecked exception thrown when a relative **put operation reaches the target buffer's limit**.

You can solve expading to 4 bytes the buffer or using [putShort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putShort(short)) that use only 2 bytes to store the number 1.

Answer (score 1):

`ByteBuffer.putInt(1)` puts an integer value into the buffer. An integer is 4 byte long (32 bit).